# Difference between allow-navigation and allow-intent

Tags: cordova, whitelist

Does any one know the difference between allow-navigation and allow-intent in cordova whitelist ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

per the documentation:

> **allow-navigation**
>
> Controls which URLs the *WebView* itself can be navigated to. Applies
>   to top-level navigations only.
>
> **allow-intent**
>
> Controls which URLs the app is allowed to ask the *system* to open. By
>   default, no external URLs are allowed.

This *whitelist* worksheet should help.
[HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

Answer (score 9):

**allow-navigation**

> Controls which URLs the WebView itself can be navigated to. Applies to
>   top-level navigations only.

In other words, this affects links in your HTML/JS code, shown directly in the WebView (which is where your HTML5 app runs).

**allow-intent**

> Controls which URLs the app is allowed to ask the system to open.

This affects requests by native code (typically originating from Cordova plugins) to the native system (Different from a security standpoint, since these requests are not 'sandboxed' in the WebView).

See here for details and types of configuration
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md

Comment: cordova-plugin-whitelist https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/