# Ionic InAppBrowser on iOS Loading White Blank Screen Error

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap, inappbrowser

I have been working with InAppBrowser for awhile now and have not run into this issue before. It was loading my URL and now it doesn't seem to want to do so.

First I have imported InAppBroswer properly, it's working 100% on Android. This is an iOS-only issue.

in my config.xml:

```
<access origin="https://www.mydomain.or/*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<!-- Call to Plugins -->
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="2.0.5" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^3.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-update" spec="^1.6.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" spec="^0.1.9" />
<engine name="android" spec="~7.0.0" />
<engine name="ios" spec="~4.5.4" />
```

My plugins seem to run fine, no lint or compile errors.

I call the browser per their documentation:

```
//construct the instance of browser we are using to launch with Ionic Native
const browser = this.iab.create('https://www.mydomain.or', '_blank','location=no');
//If Browser is Hidden Display
browser.show();
```

There are NO errors being reported in the console for WKWebView at all, but I get this below image on both simulator and device.
[image: iOS Error]

Steps Taken to Try and resolve this issue are:
Securty Steps with iOS, WhiteList is added to the Plugins--Please see above plugin list.
I have added the checks to the plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>localhost</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>www.mydomain.or</key>
    <dict/>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

This has been known to help with similar issues in the past.
I also added a Meta Tag to my index as this was something that has helped others in the past as well:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; style-src 'self’; connect-src https://www.mydomain.or; script-src 'self’; media-src *">
```

This also did not help me out at all. Anyone who may know what the cause of this is would be of great help. I feel like I am at my wits end with this error and want to be able to solve this but know the underlying reason why this is happening as well to avoid it in the future.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have struggle with this problem until recently.

In **config.xml**

```
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
```

This tag seems to solve this problem.

--- **update** --

**info.plist**

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: This didn't seem to solve the issue for me, I still get the same result. What are some of the methods you used to troubleshoot this? hopfully the information i provied was enough detail to help get an idea of the steps ive done so far

Comment: Could you upload your **config.xml** for clarifying the problem?
I will also upload my info.plist for clarifying. Please check my answer again.

Comment: I didn't have systemical approach to solve this problem because it is obvious that this is one of permission problems. So I just browsed lots of documents and pages with trials and errors.

Comment: Thank you, I did find out the problem. info.plist should be updated by defualt now with Ionic CLI when you run 'ionic cordova platform add ios'. It also appears that '<allow-navigation href="*" />' is the same as <allow-intent href="*" />. The issue was security related but was able to address it with the answer i provided

Comment: Interesting. It can be more secure solution. However, **<allow-navigation href="" />** is related to 'Webview navigation', whereas **<allow-intent href="" />** is related to ''system to open". 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35374403/6627660

Comment: I did not know this, thank you. I will also add this.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
I was able to address this issue by adding:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src gap://ready file://* *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *”>
```

This is added to the header of your index.html file.
My above question clearly has some syntax errors in this but won't call an error when building to Android or iOS.

You could, however, add a Build tool to write a script to check for this tag in your index.html.